# mongo $in opposed to nested documents for pairs

Tags: algorithm, mongodb

Has anyone working experience with pairs using name:boolean versus numeric permutation-type representation, and best shown as such. The following is a section of a single record/row.

```
{ ... {status { working: true, married: false }} ...}
```

versus

```
{ ... {status: 3} ... }
```

where in the latter we need a permutation of
(not-working+not-married=1; working + not-married=2; not-working + married=3; working + married=4)

Each then require their respective queries:

```
{status.married: true}
```

vs

```
{status: {$in : [3,4]}}
```

A further consideration is that most queries will not be single phrase but a union/intersection such as `{status.married: true}, {status.working: true}`  or  `{$or: [{status.married: true}, {status.working: true}]}`

The latter form is the simpler `{status: {$in : [2,3,4]}}`

Considerations include a single vs two indices.

Im not sure what is more 'readable' It seems easier to refactor the permutation style. But the client needs to know the proper sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros of the boolean approach:

1. queries are explicit/readable
2. document is readable/self-explanatory
3. supports more flexible queries (all queries using numeric permutation-type must be using equality/inequality or "$in")
4. I would actually argue this is *easier* to refactor, because it is not based on implicit rules of the representation of the data (e.g. the order of the fields)

Pros of numeric permutation-type:

1. queries are shorter (and arguably simpler?) (but not self-explanatory)
2. only one field to create an index on
3. documents are smaller

I don't think there's an inherent speed advantage to one over the other. It depends on the data and the actaul queries you run.

Consider which of the above you actually care about, and make your decision based on that.

My tendency is always to go with the explicit ("-is-better-than-implicit") one.

Comment: some good points worth considering. thnx. id argue with regard to point 3 of the boolean approach. doesnt boolean demand equlity/inequality vs numerical of eq, ne gt, lt, gte, lte and even mod

Comment: @GabeRainbow I'm not sure I get your point. I admit using the word "must" is an exaggeratng, but I consider using numeric operators a trickery. Also, suppose you want to store 10 boolean values, `b1` to `b10`. Encoding them in a 10-bit value, do you have a *simple and readable* way to construct a query like `b2 && b6`? If it's not simple and readable, it's hard to consider it flexible.

Comment: im thinking its easier to refactor to `{status: 20}` and include a greater number of options. versus the extensive `{status { working: true, married: false, blah1: true, ... , blah18: false }}`. admittedly the enum is longer. its like an system or error code status. thanks